# MonoMac Sqlite version

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono, monomac

I am developing an app using MonoMac which uses Sqlite database as a data storage. I am using classes from Mono.Data.Sqlite namespace to access the database. On OS X 10.7.4 SqliteConnection.SqliteVersion property reports 3.6.23.1 (released on 2010 March 30) Running "select sqlite_version() AS sqlite_version" in sqlite shell reports 3.7.4. Ideally I would like to use the latest version of Sqlite available currently 3.7.14.1.

How do I do that? I think I need to get dylib file of the new Sqlite version and put it in the same folder as my application. Is that correct? Where do I get the dylib file for the latest version? How do I distribute it with my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can recompile System.Data.SQLite using MonoMac very easily, it is an open source project.

You can download the source code from here:

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/timeline?n=20&y=ci

And you can recompile the managed version hosted on Google code:

This is an article about it:

http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/08/SQLite-Has-Been-Ported-to-.NET

And this is the Google-code link:

http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/

Comment: I can recompile it but it needs a native library doesn't it? Where do I get the Sqlite native library for Mac?

Comment: One minute, and i will give you the link

Comment: There are a managed version (Not native) of sqlite, this is the link: http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/08/SQLite-Has-Been-Ported-to-.NET

Comment: I'm aware of that but it is slower and it's not the latest version of Sqlite.

Comment: You can use the binaries of mac version to recompile System.Data.Sqlite, but I think it is more easier to use managed one, it's version not that old, it is 3.7.7.1, and it is being updated from time to time, I think it is a good choice.